# How to view glibc compilation options

Tags: linux, glibc

Glibc 2.10(or any >2.10) with compile flag **PER_THREAD** and **ATOMIC_FASTBINS** behaves totally different then glibc 2.10 without those flags.

If my Linux is using glibc 2.10 I still don't know the exact version because it doesn't say anything about compilation flags. Ubuntu may use those flags in theirs glibc and Debian not?

How to list used compilation parameters, having glibc shared library file?

Comment: Glibc 2.10 is really old. Don't use it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You won't find this information in `/lib/libc.so.6`.  Though, if you're running Debian or Ubuntu you can still grab the source package (`apt-get source libc6`) and have a look at `debian/rules` file.

You can also write a quick test that checks glibc behavior and conclude if it has been compiled with these flags or not.

Comment: Not really true, see my answer.

Comment: OP was asking for retrieving compilation parameters